# Reference nearby cells in Excel

Tags: excel

I realize this may not be the best place for this, but I need some help with Excel formulas.  I am trying to have one cell reference another in the same row, without declaring the cell by number.  This way, when I sort them the references do not become mixed, often with the bottom of the table having formulas that reference the top.  For example:

```
=SUMIF(Team_Number_Hub,'Gross Stats'!A3,Autonomous_Assist_Hub)
```

I would like to replace 'Gross Stats'!A3 with something that can reference only the cell 3 columns to the left, instead of that specific cell, which will often change places.  If possible, I would like to do this without additional coding, but if that is necessary I'm up for it.

Comment: Have a look at `OFFSET`, it might be what you're after

Comment: Do you mean that the cell A3 might go up to A2 or down to A4, depending on how the sorting goes?

Comment: Essentially. I'm sorting 500 rows, so often row 498 will have references to row 4.

Comment: Made some quick tests, and it looks like OFFSET will be perfect.  Here goes...

Comment: " I'm sorting 500 rows, so often row 498 will have references to row 4"  - sounds like your layout of your data is not well planned or you don't know about absolute and relative references A1 , $A1 A$1 and $A$1

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to switch notation (for Excel 2013, Options, Formulas, Working with formulas, check R1C1 reference style) where the above formula would become:

```
   =SUMIF(Team_NUmber_Hub,'Gross Stats'!RC[-3],Autonomous_Assist_Hub)
```

If copied to the left or right this formula does not change but the cell reference applied from `Gross Stats` does. If a specific column is required even with such copying then the square brackets should be removed.